# Let $f_1,...,f_n$ be an enumeration of all computable functions in N to N. Prove $h(n)=f_n(n)$ is not calculable.

Tags: logic

Let $f_1,...,f_n$ be an enumeration of all calculable functions in N to N. Prove $h(n)=f_n(n)$ is not calculable.

I don't really know where to start here, any hint appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what is a calculable function, but the argument you want seems to be some kind of [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Let us assume $h$ is calculable. Then, so is $1+h$. This means $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, f_{n_0}=1+h$. What is $h(n_0)$?

Comment: +1. Note for the OP that this breaks down if we allow *partial* functions, and indeed there are computable enumerations of the computable partial functions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. If i get it right, we arrive at a contradiction with $h(n_0)=h(n_0)+1$.

Comment: Noah, by partial functions, do you mean functions computable on a part of $\mathbb{N}$